# SPSS Bootstrap with custom sample size

Tags: spss

I have a very large sample of 11236 cases for each of my two variables (ms and gar). I now want to calculate Spearman's rho correlation with bootstrapping in SPSS.

I figured out the standard syntax for bootstrapping in SPSS with bias corrected and accelerated confidence intervals:

```
DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.
BOOTSTRAP
  /SAMPLING METHOD=SIMPLE
  /VARIABLES INPUT=ms gar 
  /CRITERIA CILEVEL=95 CITYPE=BCA  NSAMPLES=10000
  /MISSING USERMISSING=EXCLUDE.
NONPAR CORR
  /VARIABLES=ms gar
  /PRINT=SPEARMAN TWOTAIL NOSIG
  /MISSING=PAIRWISE.
```

But this syntax is resampling my 11236 cases 10000 times.

How can i achieve taking a random sample of 106 cases (√11236), calculate Spearman's rho and repeat 10000 times (with new random sample of 106 cases each bootstrap step)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the sample selection procedures - Data > Select Cases.  You can specify an approximate or exact random sample or select specific cases.  Then run the BOOTSTRAP and NONPAR CORR commands.

Comment: Will this take a new random sample of 106 every time the `NONPARR CORR` runs?

Comment: That is up to you.  If you use the random option on set seed, the random numbers used for the draw will be different every time.  Alternatively, you can set the seed to a fixed value to get a reproducible sequence of random numbers.